# How should this exercise in CH Edwards Advanced Calculus of Several Variables be read?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation

This is from https://www.scribd.com/read/282634061/Advanced-Calculus-of-Several-Variables
I've included a screen-scrape, a transcription, and a detailed image of the problematic detail from the hard copy text. $\mathit{v}$ means volume.

My question is, how should the final inequality in the statement of this Exercise IV 5.1 be read?  Should it be as I have transcribed it?

$$\mathit{v}\left(\mathit{f}\left(Q_{1}\right)\right)\le\left(cr/N\right)^{n}.$$

Or, perhaps a subscript $i$ in $Q_i:$

$$\mathit{v}\left(\mathit{f}\left(Q_{i}\right)\right)\le\left(cr/N\right)^{n}?$$

Or, perhaps the entire cube $\mathcal{Q}$ without a subscript is intended; as in:

$$\mathit{v}\left(\mathit{f}\left(\mathcal{Q}\right)\right)\le\left(cr/N\right)^{n}?$$

Or could it be that the exponent $n$ should be $k,$ as in

$$\mathit{v}\left(\mathit{f}\left(Q_{i}\right)\right)\le\left(cr/N\right)^{k}?$$

> Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^{k},$ with $k<n.$ If $\mathit{f}:\mathbb{R}^{k}\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a $\mathscr{C}^{1}$ mapping, show that $\mathit{f}(\mathcal{A})$ is negligible. *Hint:* Let $\mathcal{Q}$ be a cube in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ containing $\mathcal{A}$, and $\mathscr{P}=\left\{ Q_{1}.\dots,Q_{N^{k}}\right\}$  a partition of $\mathcal{Q}$ into $N^{k}$ cubes of edge-length $r/N,$ where $r$ is the length of the edges of $\mathcal{Q}.$ Since $\mathit{f}$ is $\mathscr{C}^{1}$ on $\mathcal{Q},$ there exists $c$ such that
> $\left|\mathit{f}\left(\mathbf{x}\right)-\mathit{f}\left(\mathbf{y}\right)\right|\le\left|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\right|$
> for all
> $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\in\mathcal{Q}.$ It follows that
> $\mathit{v}\left(\mathit{f}\left(Q_{1}\right)\right)\le\left(cr/N\right)^{n}.$
> [image]

[image]

Comment: If you thinjk about what's needed to show $f(A)$ is negligible it seems clear it should be $v(f(Q_i))$.

Comment: I think I understand.  It's basically squeezing $f(Q)$ which can be shown to be of a lower degree than a bounding n-volume.  I was thinking in terms of local differentials and linear mappings.